# Pegar dados de session com foreach

Tags: php, foreach

parece simples, mas estou a noite toda pesquisando e testando diversos métodos e nao consigo nada. Entao, resolvi postar.

Tenho o seguinte item na `session`:

```
["prefixo1"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["getCreatedTime"]=>
    int(1618373454)
    ["getCaption"]=>
    string(17) "teste app legenda"
    ["getCommentsCount"]=>
    int(3)
    ["getLikesCount"]=>
    int(4)
    ["getLink"]=>
    string(39) "https://..."
    ["getImageHighResolutionUrl"]=>
    string(294) "https://..."
  }
```

Meu código para teste:

```
*linha 59:* foreach ($_SESSION as $array) {
*linha 60:* foreach($array as $key => $midia) {
*linha 61:* print "$key : $midia<br>";
*linha 62:* }
*linha 63:* }
```

Resultado, em tese, parece satisfatório...

```
getCreatedTime : 1618373661
getCaption : teste app legenda
getCommentsCount : 3
getLikesCount : 4
getLink : https://...
getImageHighResolutionUrl : https://...
```

Tenho os erros:

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given > **on line 60**
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, int given > **on line 60**
```

Para exibir os dados, por exemplo, nao tenho nenhum retorno

```
$midia['getCreatedTime'];
```

Ainda obtenho o erro:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "getCreatedTime"
```

Onde estou errando?

**Editado:**
Estou salvando dessa maneira na `session`

```
$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]['getCreatedTime'] = $media->getCreatedTime();
$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]['getCaption'] = $media->getCaption();
$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]['getCommentsCount'] = $media->getCommentsCount();
$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]['getLikesCount'] = $media->getLikesCount();
$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]['getLink'] = $media->getLink();
$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]['getImageHighResolutionUrl'] = $media->getImageHighResolutionUrl();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Junior! Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em português!

Ao usar `$midia['getCreatedTime']` você está tentando chamar o índice `getCreatedTime` de `$midia`, que não é um array, mas sim uma string/int dentro do segundo `foreach`.

Se você quiser usar da maneira anterior, elimine o segundo `foreach`. Dessa forma, `$midia` passará a ser um array e você conseguirá acessar seus índices, como no exemplo abaixo:

```php
foreach ($_SESSION as $midia) {
    echo $midia['getCaption'];
}
// teste app legenda
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas! Desta forma eu tentei, e obtenho o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Comment: Em vez de dar o `echo $midia`, troca para `var_dump($midia)` e manda aqui o resultado.

Comment: acabei de postar como uma resposta, e uma forma que eu consegui pegar os valores, mas ainda não é como eu preciso.

Comment: Você precisa dos nomes dos índices (tipo `prefixo1`)?

Comment: Nao preciso, preciso apenas dos valores... No caso, sao 10 registros.

Comment: Você tem certeza que está passando os valores certos para `$_SESSION`? Tenta ver se ela não está vazia. Aqui eu fiz o teste e meu exemplo deu certo.

Comment: Sim, os registros existem. Com `var_dump($_SESSION);` posso conferir e estão lá. Mas aparecem na forma que postei na pergunta original.

Comment: Olha, pode ser que isso resolva: https://phpsandbox.io/n/black-mouse-em7m-idprk. Se resolver, por favor, me avise que eu atualizo minha resposta.

Comment: Sim, desta forma resolveu o problema. A questao agora que nao acertei foi pegar os dados... `$value['getCaption'];` por exemplo nao me retorna nada.

Comment: Você ainda não entendeu como o foreach funciona. `$value` do exemplo sempre vai ser o valor do elemento `getCaption` ou de qualquer outro elemento. Ele não é um array. Se você quiser fazer chamando os valores desse jeito, mantenho minha resposta a mesma: use somente um foreach. Atualizei o exemplo para você dar uma olhada.

Comment: Se você quiser acessar o valor do `getCaption` do `prefixo1`, por exemplo, sem usar um foreach, basta utilizar `$_SESSION['prefixo1']['getCaption']`.

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, funcionou. Neste segundo exemplo, aqui nao funciona. Tenho o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in

Comment: Eu consigo acessar outros dados da session, em outras paginas, da forma que esta no seu exemplo, mas somente estes dados prefixo que eu nao consigo. Veja como esta minha session:https://ideone.com/Hs7QZ8 acho que posso estar misturando array com objetos? isso existe? pelos erros...

Comment: Pelo var_dump, não são objetos, mas arrays mesmo. Sem outra parte do código fica difícil te ajudar. Como você está trabalhando com $_SESSION, sugiro verificar se você iniciou ela na página que você a utiliza. Se você não usar `session_start()`, `$_SESSION` ficará vazia.

Comment: Qual parte vc precisaria? De ante mão, obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente estou há um dia inteiro travado nisso. Na pergunta original, postei como eu guardo os dados na session. E estou usando sim o session_start().

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Estava na forma que eu estava salvando os dados na session, por exemplo. Estava salvando assim: `$_SESSION['prefixo'.$key]` e agora estou salvando assim `[ $_SESSION['prefixos'][$key]` e agora consigo acessar conforme seus exemplos. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Novas atualizações.

Assim eu consigo percorrer e pegar os valores:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['prefixo1'] as $key => $value) {
echo "$key: $value<br>";
}
```

Porém preciso informar o nome da `session`. No caso eu tenho 10 registros destes. Tenho que fazer 10x este codigo?

O comando `var_dump($midia);` me resulta:

```
array(6) {
["getCreatedTime"]=>
int(1618373661)
["getCaption"]=>
string(17) "teste app legenda"
["getCommentsCount"]=>
int(3)
["getLikesCount"]=>
int(4)
["getLink"]=>
string(39) "https://..."
["getImageHighResolutionUrl"]=>
string(294) "https://..."
}
```